# Understanding bind(this) inside jquery bind function

Tags: jquery, scope, bind

I see a lot of the following code in well written jquery code and I have searched all over the web trying to find an answer.

```
$(document).bind('someEvent',function(arg1) {
   this.something
}.bind(this));
```

What is the purpose of the .bind right after the function declaration inside the initial bind call? It would really help if a simple example could be written showing the difference visually with and without the nested bind.

I know it has something to do with global versus local scope I think.

Thanks so much

Sean

Comment: First is `jQuery.bind`, the second is `Function.prototype.bind`. So they are 2 completely different functions that just have similar names. PS: nothing about scope, but about context actually.

Comment: This should help: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/23/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's bind is simply a way to attach an event handler. For example, these two are essentially the same

```
$(document).click(function(){});
$(document).bind('click',function(){});
```

Bind was originally used instead of the now preferred method of `on` (as of version 1.7).

Javascript's bind is a way to attach a lexical environment to a function. Essentially it overwrites `this` to be the passed context. These two are equivalent

```
var self = this;
$(document).click(function(){
 console.log(self);
});
```

and

```
$(document).click(function(){
 console.log(this);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: "Bind is deprecated for jQuery versions after 1.7" --- is it? Have you confused it with `$.live()`?

Comment: @zerkms - "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." Does that indicate deprecated to you? Or does it simply mean it is no longer in use but still supported (which I had interpreted as deprecated). I am willing to edit that part of my answer.

Comment: when something is deprecated in jQuery - they state that explicitly and put to the http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ So from my perspective `.bind()` doesn't look like deprecated. I agree it's not useful anyway though.

Comment: @zerkms - I see, I hadn't realized they made the differentiation between the two states. Updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't write the code. I am looking at code used by Splunk to implement modules. I appreciate the deprecation comment though so I write code that is more in line with current practice.